# Google map add level for source and destination location

Tags: google-maps, web, geolocation

Click [here](http://www.geo-mobile.net/autobook/getacab.php?latitude=53.3930&longitude=-3.0140")
I want to do this type of job.I did the first thing.While one select a pickup location it will bw selected on the map using "GeoComplete" Javascript.

This is how I did the functionalities. Click [here](http://bio-zyme.mn/home.php)
I want to add the symbol for the drop off address like the first link.How can I do that?
If you need any resource please tell me.
And is it possible to do that using Google Map API?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example from Google Maps, all is possible

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete